# How to handle multiple incoming connections in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, stdin

I create a server with Node.js:

```
var net = require('net');

var PORT = 8181;

var server = net.createServer(

  function(socket) {
    console.log(this.address());

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
      var msg = data.toString().replace(/\n$/, '');
      console.log('got: ' + msg);
    });

    process.stdin.on('readable',

      function() {

        var chunk = process.stdin.read();

        if (chunk !== null) {

          socket.write(chunk);
        }
      }
    )

    socket.write('heyyo\n');
  }
)
```

Now, when multiple connections are coming in, this server sends out the typed in line only to the first connection.

I have two questions:

- what is a standard way to handle this, i.e. to store the incoming sockets into an array?
- exactly what happens that causes the `readable` event not to reach the other connections' callback function?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using a library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/). It makes handling connect/disconnect as well as placing sockets in rooms very simple. Additionally you can get the full list of available rooms and connected sockets through the adapter class it offers. A functional example is available in the docs.